# Sum of rectangle areas formed by set of coordinates

Tags: algorithm

I am given a set of N 2D coordinates. Pair every possible 2-combination of

coordinates, then we can form N * (N - 1) / 2 rectangles that are parallel to

both axes with the two points being adjacent vertices. Now I'm required to find

the sum of the area of these rectangles, where brute-forcing (i.e. iterating

through all combinations) gives TLE. So my best attempt so far was this:

```
For example, if N = 5, then for all coordinates (xi, yi) where 0 <= i < N:

the sum of rectangle areas would be

(x0 - x1) * (y0 - y1) +
(x0 - x2) * (y0 - y2) +
          .
          .
          .
(x3 - x4) * (y3 - y4)

=

x0y0 + x1y1 - x0y1 - x1y0 +
x0y0 + x2y2 - x0y2 - x2y0 +
            .
            .
            .
x3y3 + x4y4 - x3y4 -x4y3

=

(N-1) * (x0y0 + x1y1 + x2y2 + x3y3 + x4y4) -
x0 * (y1 + y2 + y3 + y4) -
x1 * (y0 + y2 + y3 + y4) -
x2 * (y0 + y1 + y3 + y4) -
x3 * (y0 + y1 + y2 + y4) - 
x4 * (y0 + y1 + y2 + y3)

we can calculate the sum of y coordinates while input,

then we can get the last four terms by simply subtracting the corresponding y coordinate 

of the coefficient (x0 ~ x4).

Thus, all five terms can be calculated with O(n) time complexity.
```

Then I found a major flaw, which really disappointed me:

This won't work when `x0 > x1, y1 > y0` (or any other two coordinates),

where the area of this rectangle becomes `x0y1 + x1y0 - x0y0 -x1y1`,

which is a different form from that in my method.

Is a solution for this problem possible (of course, without making the time

complexity O(n^2) ), or the algorithm for this is actually a completely

different one?

Edit: Memory Usage is not a problem

Edit 2: coordinates could repeat, or have same x(y) value. In such case, the area is 0

Comment: will you calculate sum of the area of each rectangle or the total area covered by this rectangles.

Comment: sum of each rectangles, so no need to consider overlapping

Answer (score 2):

Your given problem can be solved in O(n*log(n)) time complexity and here's how we can tackle it:

Let's fixate a point (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>) for which we would like to calculate the sum for all possible rectangles which can be formulated using this point.

The formula for the same would be:

[image: Formula]

For all x<sub>i</sub> and y<sub>i</sub> where, (x<sub>0</sub> ≥ x<sub>i</sub> && y<sub>0</sub> ≥ y<sub>i</sub>), the formula can be simply broken down to

= ∑ (x<sub>0</sub>y<sub>0</sub> + 
x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub>) - (x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>0</sub> + x<sub>0</sub>x<sub>i</sub>)

Now let's discuss how we can compute each of the component of the formula in O(log(n)).

- x<sub>0</sub>y<sub>0</sub> ~ which is simply the product of the current point which can be calculated easily in O(1)
- x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>i</sub> ~ the sum of the product of all x-coordinate and y-coordinate of all the points such that x<sub>0</sub> ≥ x<sub>i</sub> && y<sub>0</sub> ≥ y<sub>i</sub>. The data structure apt to query such a figure can be a 2D Binary Indexed Tree (BIT) or a 2D Segement Tree. It's a beautiful data-structure which I would really recomment you to read about it online. I would prefer a 2D BIT in the given scenario because they are much easier to code. A link to one of my implementaion is here: https://github.com/nileshsah/advanced-data-structures/blob/master/2d_Binary_Indexed_Tree.cpp
- x<sub>i</sub>y<sub>0</sub> ~ which is the y<sub>0</sub> multiplied by the sum of all x<sub>i</sub> such that y<sub>i</sub> ≤ y<sub>0</sub> and x<sub>i</sub> ≤ x<sub>0</sub>, for which we can maintain another 2D BIT for the sum of all x<sub>i</sub>'s in a given x-y range. We can then retreive this value in O(log(n))
- x<sub>0</sub>y<sub>i</sub> ~ which is the x<sub>0</sub> multiplied by the sum of all y<sub>i</sub> such that x<sub>i</sub> ≤ x<sub>0</sub> and y<sub>i</sub> ≤ y<sub>0</sub>, for which we maintain a different 2D BIT for the sum of all y<sub>i</sub>'s in a given x-y range. We can then retreive this value in O(log(n))

For all the rest of the cases, we just need to make minor tweaks to the formula in terms of the sign related to each of the above-mentioned components and the sum range to be calculated using the prefix-sum array or the 2D BIT tree.

I'm willing to explain more if required. Hope this provides you a good starting point to move forward with your given problem. Cheers! :)

Comment: shouldn't the condition of  xiy0 and x0yi be "all xi / yi such that xi <= x0 & yi <= y0"?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, overlooked that in a hurry. have updated my answer. Let me know what you feel about it now.

Comment: Now I understand how 1D BIT works, but can you elaborate more on the implementation of 2D BIT for this particular case? Since all examples I found on the net are for matrices, which isn't my case.

Comment: @Agrit I'll try to formulate an answer for you using 2D BIT for your given question. Would that be useful to you?

Comment: that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

use ABS(x_i - x_j ) * ABS (y_i - y_j)

Since you are summing area of each rectangle. This means that the areas of the rectangles are independent of each other. So, you have to generate O(n^2) rectangles and find the area of each of them so O(n^2).

Think about the simple cases; where points are (0,0),(2,1),(1,2). And conclude that you have to calculate all of the areas.

If you are calculating the are produced by the coverage of all the rectangle, that will be a different scenario.

Comment: I originally thought so, but a solution with O(n^2) gives TLE so there has to be a more efficient solution.